# SQL Select and merge the result to multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a table that store the relational between two other table that look like this

```
id_post | id_formation
______________________
 1      |    1
 1      |    3
 3      |    2
 3      |    4
```

I want to select and store this result to array of array:

example (in this case):

```
array(
      1=>array(1,3),
      3=>array(2,4)
     )
```

Could anyone tell me the SQL statement to do this? or PHP code to format the result like above ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This creates the array you want:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id_post, id_formation FROM table");

$array = array(); //empty array to hold result
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $array[$row['id_post']][] = $row['id_formation'];
}

//print result
print_r($array);
```

Comment: Common recommendation in SO would be "don't use `mysql_*` functions any more" - especially you're giving an answer. Also, your code wouldn't work because `$array[$row["id_post"]]` is not an array, so `$array[$row["id_post"]][]` would throw error. You'll have to initialize it first: `if(empty($array[$row["id_post"]])) $array[$row["id_post"]]=array();`.

Comment: This code works. You do not need to initialize an array before pushing an item onto it in PHP. One will be created automatically. No notices, warnings or errors will be thrown even with `error_reporting(E_ALL)`. We really, really don't need to turn every single question into a lesson on your database driver preference. This is a question about PHP array syntax, and does not involve any user input.